# Querying for count for specific Event id using Powershell in Windows 2008 R2 server

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

```
$ComputerName = "testserver"
$EventLogNames=@("System") 
$EventStartDate = (((Get-Date).addDays(-30)).date)
$EventEndTime = (Get-Date)

$EventCritea_Patch = @{logname = $EventLogNames; StartTime=$EventStartDate;     
EndTime=$EventEndTime; id=1074}

$events_patch = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $ComputerName -FilterHashTable    
$EventCritea_Patch  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Write-host  Count is $events_patch.count
$counts_patch = $events_patch.count
Write-host $counts_patch
```

It is a Powershell code snippet for querying a Event Viewer in Windows 2008 server and return the count of occurences

Whenever I run this script and If I change the "`(((Get-Date).addDays(-30)).date)`" such that only one event of that event id is present. I get `$events_patch.count` as 0 instead of expected value of 1. But If more than one records are written by Get-Event then I get correct value for `$events_patch.count`. Please advise.

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do (and what programming language you are using)

Comment: It is a Powershell code snippet for querying a Event Viewer in Windows 2008  server and return the count of occurences.